# Geting last file uploaded out of a number of dir

Tags: php, glob, scandir

I am going to have one directory with multiple sub-directories. 
I want to be able to get the last, one, uploaded/modified flv out of each directory and be able create a formatted list that can be outputted.

I have used glob and foreach to create lists of folder items before but not sure how to accomplish this, and just return one file out of a number of sub-directories.

Any help will be appreciated

Thank you!

Comment: You can use the DirectoryIterator to iterate through your directories: http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php. You can then go through each file and use DirectoryIterator::getMTime() on it to get the modified time, do a compare and then slect the most recently modified one.

Comment: would that give me the last modified out of the entire dir or last modified out of each sub directory? am trying to get the last modified out of each sub directory and create a list out of that.

Comment: With the iterator, you should be able to get the modified time for either a directory or a file, depending on what's being pointed to by the iterator.

Comment: well is there a way to piont it to a direcotry that only has some number of sub directories and it pull one file out of each sub directory to create a list? without having to piont it to each sub directory just to the main directory...? does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$result = array();
foreach (new DirectoryIterator('/path/to/dir') as $item) {
    if (!$item->isDot() && $item->isDir()) {
        $result[$item->getFilename()] = $m = null;
        foreach (new DirectoryIterator($item->getPathname()) as $subItem) {
            if ($subItem->isFile() && $m < $subItem->getMTime()) {
                $result[$item->getFilename()] = $subItem->getFilename();
                $m = $subItem->getMTime();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ok am trying this script, i have a folder with this script and a folder called listing. inside listing is three folder with files in it. to call to listing would the path be '/listing' if its right next to the script? at the moment it does not display anything... ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You're locking for [filemtime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php)

Comment: well i can see where that would give the time but that does not tell me how i can create a list of files out of multipl sub directories.